# Move layout above a certain view after softkeyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

For starters, I would like to clarify that I am able to scroll through my views, that when the soft-keyboard is shown, my layout scrolls to the EditText with focus, and everything works as expected.

The issue I am having is that I added a new view below the last EditText that needs to be visible while the user is typing. However, when the user clicks on the EditText and the keyboard comes up, it scroll the layout exactly below the EditText, hiding my other view.

For clarification, this is the layout before clicking on the EditText:

[image]

When I click on the last EditText, the following happens:

[image]

I would like to make the TextView (in green) visible while the user types.

Also, keep in mind that I have a custom layout which the parent view is a LinearLayout. This layout contains all of those EditTexts and TextView. That view is then included on another Layout that uses a ScrollView.

I have tries using `scrollTo` to a certain extend, but with no success.

Has anyone faced this issue before or have an idea of how I could overcome it?

I appreciate the help.

Thanks!